# How to use query string in asp.net mvc layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am getting confuse in understanding the query string and routing concept in asp.net mvc, and I will appreciate if some one can please help.

**My problem is:**

I have a login page where user will enter the Username, password and Id. After successful login I like to take the Id and pass it to my Profile page. Now profile page is part of layout page along with two other links.

```
 <nav class="main">               
            <ul class="menu" >
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Profile", MVC.Profile.Index(), new { Id = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Configuration", MVC.Configuration.Index(),new { Id = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Transaction", MVC.Transaction.Index(), new { Id = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() })</li>
            </ul>            
        </nav>
```

From my login page I am using the following code to Redirect the user to Profile page.

> return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new { Id =
>   viewModel.Id });

Now how can i pass the same value to configuration and transaction page, they are just action links on layout page.I thought of using Request.QueryString like below:

```
new { Id = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()
```

but this is **throwing object reference exception.**

my routing look like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So after you are redirecting to the `Index` action of your `Profile` controller, make sure your action takes in a `int` parameter like below and return it to the `Profile` view:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
   return View(id);
}
```

Render your links in the Profile's `Index` view like below:

```
@model int

 <nav class="main">               
            <ul class="menu" >
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Index", new { Id = @Model })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Configuration", "Index",new { Id = @Model })</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Transaction", "Index", new { Id = @Model })</li>
            </ul>    
    </nav>
```

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Hello Thanks, yes my profile controller take id as parameter. but these action links are are part of layout page. Are you suggesting me to remove these link from layout page and put it in each individual page?

Comment: @Vin05 No. You can do the same thing that I did above in your layout page and it will work the same. Your `Model` will be filled with whatever data you sent from your controller `View(id)`.

Comment: @Vin05 I have uploaded a sample application here: http://www.sendspace.com/file/crarpc

Comment: Hello, Many thanks for uploading the solution,but i have another doubt please,  as you are passing View(id) from ProfileController, I am already passing my ViewModel from profile controller. I can not pass another int value can I?

Comment: No. Your model can be of one type only. I used `int` to make things simple. So, you can wrap whatever you like in the ViewModel of yours and you can pick it out in your View e.g. `@Model.Id`.